# Lucene : Search with partial words

Tags: java, search, lucene

I am working on integrating Lucene in our application. Lucene is currently working, for example when I am searching "Upload" and there is some text called "Upload" in a document, then it works, but when I search "Uplo", then it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Code :

```
  Directory directory = FSDirectory.open(path);
                IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
                IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);

                QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser("contents", new SimpleAnalyzer());
                Query query = queryParser.parse(text);
                TopDocs topDocs = indexSearcher.search(query, 50);
                for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : topDocs.scoreDocs) {
                    org.apache.lucene.document.Document document = indexSearcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
                    objectIds.add(Integer.valueOf(document.get("id")));
                    System.out.println("");
                    System.out.println("id " + document.get("id"));
                    System.out.println("content " + document.get("contents"));
                }
                return objectIds;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Upload' might be ONE Token in your Lucene index where a Token would be the smallest entity non splittable further. If you want to match partial words like 'Uplo' then it is better to go for [Lucene NGram Indexing](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/analyzers-common/index.html?org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenizer.html). Note that if you go for NGram indexing you will have higher space requirements for your inverted index.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it, currently it is working with WildCard characters, but whenever the search phrase contains a number, I am not getting any results back. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, for Lucene a Token is a Token, it does not matter whether its all English or it is Alphanumeric. Even if your tokens contain a number, for example Bond777 and you search for 777 you would get Bond777 as your result if you have used NGrams. The advantage here is that you can even search for characters in middle, something like 'nd77' and you would get the right results. However as I said, this is all at expense of higher space complexity. On the contrary, Wildcard queries, based on position of wildcard can result in higher time complexities and you have to insert  '*' at appropriate place.

Comment: Currently, we would have to modify a lot for changing indexing mechanism, as all indexes are created and it took a heck load of time to crawl and index. But with wildcard, I am not getting results for 777, but getting results for 777Bond or Bond.

Comment: It can be an issue in your Analysis chain and you might be using a WordDelimiterFilter which is splitting on a number. If this is the case then splitOnNumerics="0" can help you solve your problem. Have a look here: https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/WordDelimiterFilter.html

Comment: Sorry for bothering you so much, but I have no XML, and unable to find something to set this in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcard searches.

"?" symbol for single character wildcard search and "*" symbol for Multiple character wildcard searches (0 or more characters).

example - "Uplo*"

Comment: This worked when I tried only Uplo, but it stopped the number based search, like when I give 50a, then I don't get any results.

Comment: @WeareBorg - That's because you aren't indexing the numbers, due to your analysis, and wildcard queries don't get analyzed. You are using SimpleAnalyzer, which eliminates everything but letters. StandardAnalyzer would work better.

Comment: Tried with StandardAnalyzer as well. I want to save a text which contains numbers(which I am doing now) and search them. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Query query = queryParser.parse(text);
```

To

```
 Query query = queryParser.parse("*"+text+"*");
```

Lucene supports single and multiple character wildcard searches within single terms (not within phrase queries).

To perform a single character wildcard search use the "?" symbol.

To perform a multiple character wildcard search use the "*" symbol.

The single character wildcard search looks for terms that match that with the single character replaced. For example, to search for "text" or "test" you can use the search:

```
te?t
```

Multiple character wildcard searches looks for 0 or more characters. For example, to search for test, tests or tester, you can use the search:

```
test*
```

You can also use the wildcard searches in the middle of a term.

```
te*t
```

Note: You cannot use a * or ? symbol as the first character of a search.

Comment: When I add a star, I don't get number based search like 50A or similar. Any ideas?